# difficulty understanding implicit differentiation steps

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm currently learning implicit differentiation (which I am having a lot of difficulties with) and I have encountered the following equation

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how we got from the third step to the fourth step. Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Apply the product rule :)

Comment: Check out Khan Academy-https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/implicit-differentiation-advanced-calc/v/implicit-derivative-of-x-2-y-2-3-5x-2y-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, given two functions $f, g$ of $x$, recall that the product rule is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, f(x)g(x) \,\Big] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x).
$$
If $y$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ is unknown, we can just write
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, y \,\Big] = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$
Now, consider the derivative of $x^{3}y$. The first function is $x^{3}$ and the second function is $y$, so that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, x^{3}y \,\Big] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, x^{3} \,\Big]\cdot y + x^{3} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, y \,\Big] = 3x^{2}y + x^{3}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$

Also recall that the chain rule for $f$ and $g$ is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, f\big(g(x)\big) \,\Big] = f'\big(g(x)\big) \cdot g'(x).
$$
Consider the derivative of $y^{2}$. This time we use the chain rule with $f(y) = y^{2}$ and $g(x) = y$, so that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, y^{2} \,\Big] = 2y \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big[\, y \,\Big] = 2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$

Comment: ah, the first steps is using the product rule, not the chain rule. Thats where I got stuck. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

Wrie your equation in the form

$$x^3y(x)+y(x)^2-x^2=5$$
then we get by the chain rule:

$$3x^2y(x)+x^3y'(x)-2y(x)y'(x)-2x=0$$